# How to put horizontal space in beamer footnote

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I would like to shift beamer footnote further to the right (ideally, I would like it centered, but I can achieve what I want by adding space to the left). I tried

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\hspace{10ex}}
```

but this did not do anytihng (interestingly adding `\vspace` works). Is there a way of achieving what I want to do?

If there is, is there a way to do it in only one frame or do I have to do it at the preamble for all footnotes?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments, always make a short test document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer normally used `\raggedright` in its default footnote template. You could redefine it to use `\centering` instead of `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
{
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \centering
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
    abc
  \footnote{text}
\end{frame} 
}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
  \footnote{text}
\end{frame}   
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; I will try that. I suppose I can remove the footnote separation line by adding ```\renewcommand\footnoterule{}``` to the definition?

Comment: @ozsu Use `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` before your frame. If you do this in the template, it will be too late.

Comment: Got it, thanks.